# Setting up custom connectors in my app

Tags: office365connectors

so currently I have an app that uses Cisco Spark, which can create connectors "webhooks" through a simple POST request. I am trying to create an app with MS teams that opens a connector "webhook" whenever a new team is created. Does Office365 Connectors support this functionality? or do the connectors need to be manually added through the MS teams application?

Answer (score 2):

At present you need to do it manually through the MS teams application for each MS team you create.